# DateTimeObject not being accepted by Django Model (that expects it)

Tags: python, django, datetime

In my **models.py** I have the following model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Notification(models.Model):
        recipient = models.OneToOneField(User)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

In **views.py**, I try to create an instance of this model via `Notification.objects.create(recipient = self.request.user, timestamp=timestamp)` where self.request.user is an instance of `User`, and timestamp equals `[datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 19, 16, 3, 2, 356585, tzinfo=<UTC>)]`. Yet for these values, when the `objects.create` command is run, I get an error: `Type error: expected string or buffer`.

The line number happens to be the `objects.create` command. I suspect my datetime object is misconfigured. The whole trace is as follows:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 86, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 139, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(object_list=self.object_list)
  File "/home/hassan/Desktop/unconnectedredditpk/links/views.py", line 135, in get_context_data
    Unseennotification.objects.create(recipient=self.request.user,timestamp=timestamp)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 149, in create
    return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 546, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 650, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 215, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1661, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 936, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 894, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 304, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 835, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 820, in get_prep_value
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 788, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 67, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Stumped about what to do here! I'm using *Django 1.5* and *Python 2.7*.

Comment: Why timestamp in a list? I can see the `[ ]`. Debug creating like this: `Notification.objects.create(recipient = self.request.user, timestamp=timestamp[0])`

Comment: Thanks for the comment  @Gocht. Helped me debug quite a bit. I think this problem runs deeper. When I print the querset the timestamp is being derived from, I see `[[<set1>],[<set2>],[<set3>],[<set4>]]`. I always thought queryset are written as `[set1, set2, set3, set4]`. This output isn't typical, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp appears to be a list with one datetime in it. It should be a datetime, for example `timestamp[0]`. It could also be a correctly-formatted string - that's the code path the exception you're seeing comes from, but it fails because the value passed in is a list rather than a string.

Comment: Follow up question: debugging shows that the querysets 'timestamp' is being derived from print as `[[<set1>],[<set2>],[<set3>],[<set4>]]`. Do you know what the internal `[]` and `<>` individually represent in that? Is this typically how quersets are represented? I always thought they'd be represented as `[set1, set2, set3, set4]`

Comment: What queryset are you printing? I don't really understand your question, sorry. It sounds like that field contains lists of 1 item each, rather than just the items themselves.

Comment: These were nested I suppose. I cleaned up my code, and used `itertools` to break down the set into a better-behaved qset. On this front, all is well now.